# PHP substr() REALLY slow when not taking first part of string

Tags: php, string, substring

I have a text file that has about 5,000 lines with each line being about 200 characters long. Each line actually contains 6 different pieces of data that I've been using `substr()` to break apart. For example, on each line, characters 0 - 10 contain the Client#, characters 10-20 contain the Matter#, etc. This is all well and good and was running faster than I even needed it to.

My problems arose when I was told by my boss that the client number has 4 leading zeros and they need to be stripped off. So I thought, no problem - I just changed my first `substr()` function from `substr(0, 10)` (start at 0 and take 10 characters) and changed it to `substr(4, 6)` (starting at the 4th character and just taking 6) which will skip the 4 leading zeros and I'll be good to go.

However, when I changed the `substr(0, 10)` to `substr(4,6)` the process grinds to a halt and takes **forever** to complete. Why is this?

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
// open the file    
$file_matters = fopen($varStoredIn_matters,"r") or exit("Unable to open file!");

// run until the end of the file
while(!feof($file_matters))
{
    // place current line in temp variable
    $tempLine_matters = fgets($file_matters);

    // increment the matters line count
    $linecount_matters++;

    // break up each column
    $clientID = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 0, 10)); // THIS ONE WORKS FINE
    //$clientID = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 4, 6)); // THIS ONE MAKES THE PROCESS GRIND TO A HALT!!
    $matterID = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 10, 10)); 
    //$matterID = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 15, 5)); 
    $matterName = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 20, 80)); 
    $subMatterName = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 100, 80)); 
    $dateOpen = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 180, 10)); 
    $orgAttorney = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 190, 3)); 
    $bilAttorney = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 193, 3)); 
    $resAttorney = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 196, 3)); 
    //$tolCode = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 200, 3)); 
    $tolCode = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 200, 3)); 
    $dateClosed = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 203, 10)); 

    // just does an insert into the DB using the variables above

}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's that? I.e. will it work for smaller data file? What is an error? Time limit?

Comment: I cannot understand that. According to implementation it shouldn't make a real difference?

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo I'm almost positive it's that - smaller data files (I.e 200 lines) process with no problem. I get timed out at about 2 minutes since that is the max execution time set on our server in our PHP config. If I change the `substr(4, 6)` back to `substr(0, 10)` it runs in about 3 seconds with 5,000 lines.

Comment: @bwoebi I know! And that's what is causing me so much frustration!

Comment: @FastTrack I cannot reproduce that…? `$s = str_repeat("1", 1 << 16); $t = microtime(1); for ($i = 0; $i < 500000; $i++) trim(substr($s, 4, 6)); print (microtime(1) - $t)."s\n"; => 1.41551303863525s` and `$s = str_repeat("1", 1 << 16); $t = microtime(1); for ($i = 0; $i < 500000; $i++) trim(substr($s, 0, 10)); print (microtime(1) - $t)."s\n"; => 1.42793393135071s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see why that would be so much slower, but you could take a look at [unpack](http://php.net/unpack) which could extract your fixed width record in one hit:

```
 $fields = unpack('A10client/A10matter/A60name ...etc... ',$tempLine_matters);
```

I did a quick benchmark using a similar record pattern to your example and found unpack was over twice as fast as using 10 substr calls in each iteration.

I'd suggest profiling your code with xdebug to see where the different really lies.

Comment: I benchmarked substr to try and repeat your findings with no luck. Could your slowness be attributed to some other operations which take longer because $clientID isn't as expected?

Comment: Very interesting - I've never used `unpack()` but will give it a try here in a few minutes when I get the chance. BTW, what do you use to benchmark your PHP scripts? I see so many ways to do it out here...

Answer (score 1):

It's not a very optimized process. You should maybe think about it a little bit more.
But if it's working right now it's the most important... 
Maybe if you get your value with two process it will be faster. For example :

```
$clientID_bis = trim(substr($tempLine_matters, 0, 10));
$clientID = trim(substr($clientID_bis, 4, 6));
```

Comment: You know what, I tried this thinking it would help - but I get the _same_ hang up I did when just doing `substr(4, 6)`

Comment: it's pretty weird behaviour :) If you comment all the other lines, just keeping the substr for clientId, you reproduce the problem ?
You cannot work with an explode on the $tempLine_matters, in order to use substr with smaller strings ?